# Close Facebook popup share after share is success or cancel

Tags: facebook, popup, share

I'm attempting to share a link on Facebook via url. I get the share to work, however instead of loading the redirectURI, I want to close the popup window. My code:

**Script**

```
function fbs_click(width, height) {
    var leftPosition, topPosition, u, t, c;
    //Allow for borders.
    leftPosition = (window.screen.width / 2) - ((width / 2) + 10);
    //Allow for title and status bars.
    topPosition = (window.screen.height / 2) - ((height / 2) + 50);
    var windowFeatures = "status=no,height=" + height + ",width=" + width + ",resizable=yes,left=" + leftPosition + ",top=" + topPosition + ",screenX=" + leftPosition + ",screenY=" + topPosition + ",toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,directories=no";
    u = 'http://' + share_content.FACEBOOK.SHARE_LINK;
    t = share_content.FACEBOOK.SHARE_TITLE;
    c = share_content.FACEBOOK.SHARE_CONTENT;
    window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=690028841132472&name='+encodeURIComponent(t)+'&display=popup&caption='+encodeURIComponent(c)+'&link='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&redirect_uri='+u, 'sharer', windowFeatures);
    return false;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onClick="return fbs_click(600, 300)" target="_blank" title="Share This on Facebook"></a>
```

I have found a similar question, that suggest to create a new page to close the popup.

Is there any way other than that?

Reference:  [Close facebook share popup after share is complete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197000/close-facebook-share-popup-after-share-is-complete)

Comment: If you are using the URL redirect version of the dialog, then user will be redirected to the URL specified, and you will have to close the popup from there yourself. Your alternative is to use the JS SDK, method `FB.ui`, to call the feed dialog; in that case, Facebook will take care of opening the popup and also closing it again after the user is done with it.

Comment: As pointed out by CBroe, alternatively you can use the share dialog of the JS SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog